# System.Text.Json: Sort by key Hashtable?

Tags: c#, json, .net-5, lexicographic

I am serializing my object using a simple:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true, IncludeFields = true};
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, options);
File.WriteAllText("output.json", jsonString);
```

However my hierarchy contains a `Hashtable`. I'd like to have the `Hashtable` content be written in a consistent manner: always order by Keys (key is string in my case).

How can I do that in .NET 5 ?

---

My question is about [`Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable) content and is no way related to ordering of class fields.

---

I cannot simply change the type of `Hashtable` to `SortedDictionary` since this would break all my existing `BinaryFormatter` serialized streams.

Comment: Use a `SortedDictionary`. The serializer will simply serialize the data in the order it's given by the collection, so you need to pick the right collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a property as a pass-through:

```
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Hashtable MyHashtable { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("MyHashtable")]
    public SortedDictionary<string, string> MyHashtableSorted 
    {
        get => new SortedDictionary<string, string>(
                     MyHashtable
                     .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                     .ToDictionary(x => (string)x.Key, x => (string)x.Value)
                );
        set {
            MyHashtable = new Hashtable();
            foreach (var x in value)
                MyHashtable.Add(x.Key, x.Value);
        }
    }
```

Or just use a `SortedDictionary` as your property type to start with...

Answer (score -1):

microsoft gives [this advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0#customize-individual-property-names) to order as you want your object properties

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace PropertyOrder
{
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        [JsonPropertyOrder(-5)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyOrder(-2)]
        public int TemperatureF { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyOrder(5)]
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyOrder(2)]
        public int WindSpeed { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var weatherForecast = new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Parse("2019-08-01"),
                TemperatureC = 25,
                TemperatureF = 25,
                Summary = "Hot",
                WindSpeed = 10
            };

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
            string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast, options);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
        }
    }
}
// output:
//{
//  "Date": "2019-08-01T00:00:00",
//  "TemperatureF": 25,
//  "TemperatureC": 25,
//  "WindSpeed": 10,
//  "Summary": "Hot"
//}
```

Comment: But that's a class (`WeatherForecast`), not a `Hashtable` as requested by OP